# Java NIO 2 Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, nio2

I am working on a distributed system based on Java NIO 2, using AsynchronousSocketChannel and AsynchronousServerSocketChannel. My task is to make authentication when client attempts to connect to a server. What is the best way to do that considering using NIO 2 (not any other I/O library)? I looked at SSL, but it's implementation supposes using special types such as SSLServerSocket and so on. Any suggestions?

Comment: SSL is a natural except that you've commtted yourself to async I/O. You don't give enough information about your requirements for any concrete answer to be possible. For example, do you mean full-blown X.509 authentication, or just username and password?

Comment: @EJP Exchanging with username and password can be done with simple exchanging bytes in CompletionHandler, I need something more complicated in terms of security, like probably SSL, but I don't really want to develop a separate library for certificates managing and keys exchanging, my part of the project is big enough.